# How to display require popup manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to display the `require` popup when a certain input is not filled or isn't filled correctly in my form. So, for doing this, I've created this form:

```
<form id="login">
<input class="form-control require" type="email"  placeholder="username" ></input>
<button type="submit">
go
</button>
</form>
```

and I put the logic inside a js function:

```
$('#login').submit(function(event)
{
   event.preventDefault();

  $(event.target).find('.require').each(function()
  {
    if($(this).val().length == 0)
    {
      this.setCustomValidity("Field Required!");
    }
    else
    {
      this.setCustomValidity('');
    }
  });

    console.log('ajax execution');
});
```

Now how you can see when the form is submitted I prevent the default event `submit`, and assign to each control a custom validation error. Now the problem's that if a field is not valorized correctly, for example is blank I get no popup displayed, instead, if I press again the submit button I can see the `require` popup appear on the UI.

Someone could help me to fix this?

I put an example JSFIDDLE [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23685/)

When you press the button for the first time no popup appear, the second time appear correctly but, this should appear the first time or anyway, each time that a particular field is not valid.

Comment: Try adding `required` to your HTML element and `return false` from the submit function if the validation false. Bearing in mind that you can't just `return false` after `this.setCustomValidity("Field Required!");` as you are in a callback function and not the submit function.

Comment: @NicholasRobinson this is another way to do this, I want set a custom validation message that is not possible with `required`

Answer (score 0):

`if($(this).val().length == 0)` this code will not properly if the input field has only space . To avoid that u should use this:

```
if($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0)
```

OR

```
if($.trim($(this).val()) == "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that the submit event is only firing once. I'm not familiar with bootstrap, so I haven't seen the setCustomValidity function before but I would guess that it is probably attaching its own listener, which is prevent the button click from triggering the submit at all.

I notice that if I type something into the text box, and fire setCustomValidity on it, it says "please enter an email address" - which I don't see in your code. If I then enter 'asdf@qwer.dfsgh', it gets validated and submits.

So it looks like you have not understood how setCustomValidity is supposed to be used. I would guess, you are probably supposed to attach it once, when the page first loads, and not repeatedly as you are doing.

Comment: I need to set customValidity each time 'cause I don't know which element is not valid

Comment: you set it when the page loads, on all of the elements, and then bootstrap handles detecting which ones are valid. You don't need to manually remove it.